# Are there token behaviours that are not supported by the 0x protocol?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, 0x, exchange-api

Sometimes swapping using 0x fail, are there certain types of tokens that are not supported? I am thinking in particular of tokens that take fees on each transfer/swap. For example the Safemoon token.

Comment: This is a question for 0x customer support.

Comment: Indeed they use SO for their customer support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that fee-on-transfer tokens are currently not supported with 0x API, other than that, any ERC20 compliant token should work just fine